How to enforce the 2nd job session in the waiting list in jenkins job
I have a jenkins job that is in such configuration:
    pipeline { 
        agent any 
        ...         
        
        stages {
          stage('Set-Up'}
             script { ... }
          }
          
          stage('Jobs') {
             parallel {
                stage('job-1') { 
                  steps { ... } 
                }
                stage('job-2') {
                  steps { ... }
                }
            }   // end of parallel 
          } //  end of Jobs
       } // end of stages 
       
       post {
          always {
             // generate allure report 
                ... 
             // Send email with the Allure report attached
                emailext(
                    body: '''${SCRIPT, template="allure-report.groovy"}''',
                    subject: "Jenkins Job '${env.JOB_NAME}--${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'  ${currentBuild.currentResult}",
                    to: params.receiver, 
                    mimeType: 'text/html')
             }  // end of always. 
     }  // end of Post 
}  // end of the pipeline 

The issue I am hitting is, if the 1st job session still in process, and the 2nd job session starts, the 2nd job session fails instantly. It will not be in the waiting list till the 1st job session ends.
And the 2nd failed job session sends such message in the email:
Groovy Template file [allure-report.groovy] was not found in $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates.

Is there a way to enforce that ?
Thanks,
Jack

What makes the job-2 stage start before the job-1 stage is still in process is this keyword:
             parallel {
                 ...
             }

If you want the job-2 stage to wait for the job-1 stage to finish before it runs you can remove the parallel block and go back to the default, sequential execution of stages.

Thanks for the message, but I think you misunderstand my question. I would like to have job-1 and job-2 running in parallel. But at the Jenkins build level, if a session which contains the job-1 and job-2  has already started, would it be possible to have the 2nd session be in the waiting. Thanks.

What's session?

The session is the period of time a jenkins job starts to kick-off, until its ending.  In my case, the job is not started by clicking the build button manually, but is from a remote curl call,  something as if:  "curl -X POST http://<jenkins_ip>:8080/job/<job_name>/buildWithParameters --user <jenkins_login_name>:<api_token>--data-urlencode ...".

It's called a "build". To not allow concurrent builds select a checkbox labelled "Do not allow concurrent builds" in your job configuration.

Thanks for the help. this is no longer an issue for me.
